# WPF MultiThreading: How can this still cause an exception? (Careful with that Dispatcher!)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, locking, dispatcher

I have the following code in a message handler (that can be invoked on any thread):

```
private readonly Dictionary<string,IView> _openedViews = new Dictionary<string,IView>();
private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

public MainView() 
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<ViewChangeMessage>(this, "adminView", m =>
    {
         var key = m.ViewName;
         lock (_lockObject)
         {
            if (_openedViews.ContainsKey(key) == false)
                _openedViews.Add(key, GetView(key));
           content.Content = _openedViews[key];
         }
         //...
    });
    //...
```

How can I still get this exception: `An element with the same key already exists in the System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.`

The exception is produced if I rapidly cause the message to be sent multiple times.

EDIT: added more context to the code, `Messenger` is from Galasoft.MVVMLight

Comment: Depends how you set your handler. This code is not enough. Maybe `_openedViews` is static and `_lockObject` is not? Need more detail.

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura: added more code to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happened:
the GetView instantiated a view, which had a long running operation somewhere (waiting on a background thread), and so that waiting wouldn't lock the UI up someone introduced this code:

```
public static void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
```

and thanks to the PushFrame, a second message was handled ON THE SAME THREAD as the first, hence the lock did nothing to stop it.
Once I've rearranged the code to this, the problem went away:

```
if (_openedViews.ContainsKey(key) == false)
{
   _openedViews.Add(key, null);
   _openedViews[key] = ServiceRegistry.GetService<IShellService>().GetView(key);
}
```

Comment: Good thing you found the problem. Please mark this as accepted for future readers to find quickly.

Comment: @Tudor: I will, once SO let's me :)

Answer (score 1):

Well in that code you posted I don't see any data race.

If `GetView` cannot cause a data race you could try to replace that entire block of locked code with a [ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378674):

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string,IView> _openedViews = 
          new ConcurrentDictionary<string,IView>();

public MainView() 
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<ViewChangeMessage>(this, "adminView", m =>
    {
         var key = m.ViewName;
         content.Content = _openedViews.GetOrAdd(key, GetView(key));
         //...
    });
    //...
```

Comment: Better yet, use the `GetOrAdd` overload that accepts a `Func<TKey,TProduct>` to avoid unnecessary instantiation of the view

Comment: @Tudor: Thanks for reassuring my thinking, that there's no real race condition in my code. It was really a thread affinity + dispatcher mixup, see my posted answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that all threads are using the same instance of lockObject? If they're not then it won't stop multiple threads getting to your add code.

Comment: given that both _openedViews and _lockObject are private readonly instance fields of the same class, no, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Move `var key = m.ViewName;` inside `lock` statement.